# excel formula to remove duplicates and select higher value row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a text file(can be loaded into Excel) with three columns. I want to remove duplicate rows(by duplicate values in row-2) and keep the only one row where row-3 is higher value. For example the date is

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
abcd 1111 1000 
efgh 1111 1001 
ijkl 2222 1002 
mnop 1111 1003 
qrst 3333 1004 
uvwx 1111 1005
xwvu 2222 1006
```

I want following output

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 
uvwx 1111 1005
xwvu 2222 1006
qrst 3333 1004
```

thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If that is a simple text file, are you sure you want to solve this with Excel?

Comment: It is actually a csv file. I thought easiest way to play with data is by moving data into excel. I tried few ways but didn't workout. I want to remove duplicates based on Col2 and want to keep the row where Col3 got highest value.

Comment: Sort by Col C, Sort by Col B, "Data" > "Remove Duplicates"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Pivot Tables. I grouped data by Col2 and Col1, and then added Col3 to values. Then applied filter TOP 1. This is what I get:

[image]

The only problem here is I changed columns position, but at least you get the values you want in seconds. After this, is just to copy and paste in other sheet with the column Order you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you bring all your data into Excel, you can sort Col1 (from Z-A), and then remove duplicates on Col2.

edit: sorry, meant sort on Col3.

Comment: Thanks, I can bring all data into excel. Data file was huge(around 50K records), so I do not want to take a risk thinking excel will keep the first/last row after sorting. I will try anyway.